# Datatables - How to peek at next few rows?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datatable that I'm looping thru...

```
 For Each drIndicator As DataRow In dtIndicatorsToProcess.Rows
```

Is there a way to "peek" at the next few rows to determine some things then continue?

Thanks!

Comment: You're better off using a for loop rather than for each, as then you can use the index to look ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the for loop, something as shown below should suitable

```
    For i = 0 To dtIndicatorsToProcess.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim drIndicator As DataRow = dtIndicatorsToProcess.Rows(i)
        '// Check ahead 2 rows
        Dim drRowToCheck As DataRow = dtIndicatorsToProcess(i + 2)

        '// Process here
    Next
```